# When using sudo to run pip "pip: command not found" but it's installed

Tags: software-installation, sudo, pip

`sudo easy_install pip`

```
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.4.1
Processing pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg
pip 1.4.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /home/nyzlfc/.local/bin
Installing pip-2.7 script to /home/nyzlfc/.local/bin
Using /home/nyzlfc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

And then when I run

```
sudo pip install -U pyyaml nltk
```

I get:

```
sudo: pip: command not found
```

Answer (score 57):

If you install pip from the Ubuntu repositories pip will work with sudo (I have used pip this way on 12.04 through to 14.04).

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: You dont always need to use sudo to install python modules. you can scope them to your user using pip install --user ipdb (for example) - from there, they are installed to ~/.local/lib/python-ver/  and the bins are placed in ~/.local/bin/  so add ~/.local/bin to your $PATH and you're g2g with non-sudo use of pip.

Comment: Good point, I was working on the fact the question was using sudo, that installing with sudo was desired. I generally do as my code is used by different users on the same system

Comment: This is not working for me, Ubuntu 20.0.4

Comment: 20.04 use this `sudo apt install python3-pip`, then use `pip3 install xxx` to install your packages

Answer (score 12):

Your pip is installed in `/home/nyzlfc/.local/bin`, which is not in the `sudo` path and with a good reason. Just add `~/.local/bin` to your path and step away of `sudo` as it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, and the reason I had this problem (on Debian) is that I installed python3.2 and python3-pip and as such, I really didn't have a pip executable, I also didn't have a pip3 executable. I have pip-3.2 executable.

As such I would also recommend doing:

```
sudo pip
```

and then pressing the tab to see the autocomplete options.

Comment: +1 sudo pip
and then pressing tab to see the autocomplete options...

did the job for me.

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks a ton for the answer

Answer (score 3):

First check your `$PATH` variable using the `echo` command:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

If `/usr/local/bin` is missing, edit the hidden file `.profile`, located in your home directory. If this file is missing, edit `.bash_profile` instead.

Add as very last `PATH` statement the following line:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

I always forgetting it myself!

- I installed pip into `~/.local/bin`
- when doing a `pip install package`, I get a `PermissionDenied` somewhere in `/usr/local/share/`, with the friendly solution `Consider using the '--user' option or check the permissions.`

Hence, do: `pip install --user package` (unless you need this package globally/for other users as well)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (also trying to install yaml) and

```
sudo pip3 install yaml
```

worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `pip install <package name>`

Try `pip3 install <package name>`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to install new package (to make sure it doesn't mess with your current python environment), I suggest switching to **root** just for installation. I found it easier. But don't forget to switch back, right after you finished installation.

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed in python3 then you can do is 
`python3 -m pip install package_name`